# Why does my priorityqueue look like this?

Tags: java, data-structures

I created a Student class:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
int id;
String name;
double cgpa;

public Student(int id, String name, double cgpa) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.cgpa = cgpa;
}

int getId() {
    return id;
}

String getName() {
    return name;
}

double getCgpa() {
    return cgpa;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "id= " + id + " name= " + name + " cgpa= " + cgpa;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student second) {
    if (getCgpa() == second.getCgpa()) {
        if (getName().equals(second.getName())) {
            return Integer.compare(getId(),second.getId());
        } else {
            return getName().compareTo(second.getName());
        }
    } else {
        return Double.compare(getCgpa(), second.getCgpa());
    }
}
}
```

Then I inserted 3 students into a max heap:

```
Student john = new Student(50, "John", 3.75);
Student mark = new Student(24, "Mark", 3.8);
Student shafaet = new Student(35, "Shafaet", 3.7);
PriorityQueue<Student> pq = new PriorityQueue<Student>(1, new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                // reverse order for max instead of min
                return s2.compareTo(s1);
            }
        }
        );
pq.add(john);
pq.add(mark);
pq.add(shafaet);
```

I expected Mark followed by John followed by Shafaet.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: What was the output?

Comment: in the debugger it dislays pq like
```pq[0] = shafaet
pq[1] = mark
pq[2] = john
```

Comment: I just ran your code, with an added `System.out.println(pq);` at the bottom, and it shows the order "Mark", "John", "Shafaet" like you expect. Closing as "can't reproduce".

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to debug there. I suggest you try to simplify your code and then unit test it in parts.

Firstly, there's really no need to implement your own `compareTo` - everything you need is in the `Comparator` class already:

```
Comparator<Student> studentOrder = Comparator
    .comparing(Student::getCgpa)
    .thenComparing(Student::getName)
    .thenComparing(Student::getId);
```

That's much easier to read and doesn't embed your order as a 'natural' ordering of Students.

Now you can unit test the comparator. E.g., using junit and assertj:

```
assertThat(new Student(1, "fred", 1.0)).usingComparator(studentOrder)
    .isLessThan(new Student(1, "fred", 1.1))
    .isLessThan(new Student(1, "gina", 1.0))
    .isLessThan(new Student(2, "fred", 1.0));
```

And so on.

Once you're confident you've got the ordering right then use it in your priority queue's constructor.

```
PriorityQueue<Student> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(studentOrder.reversed());
```